# Rendering a list item using ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This is the javascript code that I have written

```
// jshint esversion: 6

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

let items = [];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     const today = new Date();

     let options = {
          weekday: 'long',
          day: 'numeric',
          month: 'long'
     };

     let day = today.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

     res.render('list', { kindOfDay: day, newListItem: items });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
     let item = req.body.newItem;

     items.push(item);

     res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log('The server started at port 3000');
});
```

and here is my ejs code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>

     <h1><%= kindOfDay %></h1>

     <ul>
          <li>Buy Food</li>
          <li>Cook Food</li>
          <li>Eat Food</li>
          <li> <% newListItem %> </li>
     </ul>

     <form action="/" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="newItem">
          <button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I launch my server and try to add a new list item in the list it shows no errors but it shows nothing except for the fact that a li is there by showing a dot.

[The webpage after entering the list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVzng.png)

Comment: It seems you are missing a "=" in <%= %> in your list item.

Comment: It is now working. Thanks. But the disk style of li is still there. Is there anything I can do about it. I want it to appear only when I add the item and press submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are always rendering the `<li></li>` element, no matter if you actually have `newListItem` or not (hence the empty dot style). You need to conditionally render the li element only if there is `newListItem`.

```
<ul>
   <li>Buy Food</li>
   <li>Cook Food</li>
   <li>Eat Food</li>
   <%if (newListItem) { %>
      <li> <%= newListItem %> </li>
   <% } %>

</ul>
```

EJS is a pretty easy templating framework to work with. You can always google "EJS conditionals", "EJS for loop" etc to see how to dispay your data.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this `<li> <% newListItem %> </li>`

with this `<li> <%= newListItem %> </li>`

Meaning of `<%=` **Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)**

to learn more about EJS with examples refer this https://ejs.co/